# Java stream with parallel elements and sequential elements

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to run a Java stream in which the first element filters in parallel to the second and third element. The second and third element can not filter parallel, because the use a shared ressource.

```
int numberOfFilteredElements = Stream.of(firstElement, secondElememt, thirdElement)
  .filter(element -> element.someFilter())
  .collect(Collectors.toSet())
  .size();
```

A Java stream can be parallel or sequential. Concating streams are only parallel if all streams are parallel. So I can not create create a parallel and sequential stream and concat them.

Any other idea how I can solve this with streams? Or do I need to need use locks like ReentrantLock in someFilter() and run the stream parallel for all elements?

Comment: This looks like a problem that would be much easier to solve without streams.

Comment: I thought the same but was interessted if there would be a nice solution with streams I could learn.

Comment: Not with streams. Method `someFilter` could - of course - synchronize or lock, but I am not sure how the stream API would react to this.

Comment: If it is only about filter then there is one way to achieve it. You can check the hashcode of `element` and decide to enter in a synchronized block or not.

Comment: Thanks. I will solve this without streams.

Answer (score 1):

We can say:

- First element is `Stream #1`.
- Second and third elements are `Stream #2`.

Then we can create a `Parent Parallel Stream` that consists of `Stream #1`, `Stream #2`:

```
    Predicate<Integer> someFilter = i -> {
        try { Thread.sleep(4000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        logger.info(i + " filtered on thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        return i != 7;
    };
    Stream<Integer> stream1 = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 3).boxed().filter(someFilter);
    Stream<Integer> stream2 = IntStream.rangeClosed(-3, -1).boxed().filter(someFilter);

    int numberOfFilteredElements = Stream.of(stream1, stream2)
            .parallel()
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .peek(integer -> logger.info("Peeked: " + integer.toString()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            .size();
    System.out.println("Set size is: " + numberOfFilteredElements);
```

Output:

```
2021-04-01 12:56:34.084  INFO 26336 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 2.966 seconds (JVM running for 5.717)
2021-04-01 12:56:38.098  INFO 26336 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : -3 filtered on thread id: 1
2021-04-01 12:56:38.098  INFO 26336 --- [onPool-worker-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : 0 filtered on thread id: 22
2021-04-01 12:56:38.100  INFO 26336 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Peeked: -3
2021-04-01 12:56:38.100  INFO 26336 --- [onPool-worker-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Peeked: 0
2021-04-01 12:56:42.100  INFO 26336 --- [onPool-worker-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : 1 filtered on thread id: 22
2021-04-01 12:56:42.100  INFO 26336 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : -2 filtered on thread id: 1
2021-04-01 12:56:42.100  INFO 26336 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Peeked: -2
2021-04-01 12:56:42.100  INFO 26336 --- [onPool-worker-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Peeked: 1
2021-04-01 12:56:46.101  INFO 26336 --- [onPool-worker-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : 2 filtered on thread id: 22
2021-04-01 12:56:46.101  INFO 26336 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : -1 filtered on thread id: 1
2021-04-01 12:56:46.101  INFO 26336 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Peeked: -1
2021-04-01 12:56:46.101  INFO 26336 --- [onPool-worker-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Peeked: 2
2021-04-01 12:56:50.102  INFO 26336 --- [onPool-worker-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : 3 filtered on thread id: 22
2021-04-01 12:56:50.102  INFO 26336 --- [onPool-worker-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Peeked: 3
Set size is: 7
```

Notice that `Stream #1` (which can be your first element) runs in parallel to `Stream #2` (which can be second and third elements).

Comment: It is very dangerous to assume that a particular limitation (the current implementation’s inability to parallelize sub-streams in `flatMap`) will persist all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am confused though. I don't see why would we expect flatMap to parallelize the sub-streams. I thought it specifies to parallelize just the parent stream, not its elements, no?

Comment: No, it does not specify anywhere that sub-streams are processed sequentially. That’s just a detail of the current implementation.